# Facebook: php upload photo and post on wall

Tags: php, facebook

new to php please forgive my silly questions.

I am creating my first fb app. It allows user to browse through their local drive and select a photo. Once it is submit, it will redirect to the next page and process to the storing onto my server first then posting to user's wall.

The application is not working really that much. The part where user browse and app storing the photo on to my server is working, but it fails to grab the photo back from my server and post it on the user's wall.

config.php:

```
 <?php
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "";
$app_key = "";
$app_secret = "";
$canvas_url = "";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!$session) {

        $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, user_photos, read_stream, read_friendlists'
        ));

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";

    }//end if session user 
else
{

        try {

        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        $updated = date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($me['updated_time']));

        echo "Hello " . $me['name'] . "<br />";
        echo "You last updated your profile on " . $updated  . "<br />" ;
        echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture'/>"; 
        }//end try getUser 
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);

        }//end catch getUser 
}//end else user
```

index.php contains the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

uploader.php run the process

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
            " has been uploaded" . "<br />";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" . "<br />";
        }
        try {
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/".$uid."/feed", "post", array("picture"=>$target_path));
    if(isset($post_id))
        echo "A new post to your wall has been posted with id: $post_id";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
```

I have been trying many different ways which i could find online but it does not work. i have tried adding $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); but receive errors.

Please advice me how i could go about getting to upload the photo onto the user wall.
Thank you very much

Comment: Doesn't facebook already let you do this?

Comment: I wanna create a app where by they will be able to upload photo through it. Then the photo will be posted to the walls and also sent to my server. I will grab these photos then display them out as a collage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this should work:

```
$target_folder = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_folder . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded" . "<br />";

    $file_path = $target_folder . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
    $arr = array();
    $arr["image"] = '@' . realpath($file_path);
    try {
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/".$uid."/feed", "post", $arr);
        if(isset($post_id))
        echo "A new post to your wall has been posted with id: $post_id";
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping, i have tried to implement your method but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @meAtStackOverflow: You are welcome! mind sharing what wasn't working from your side so that other users learn from your experience?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i am unsure which part went wrong. I believe it is my logic that is playing the trick. Is my first time doing php facebook. haha. till now i am still not familiar with this. I have change the way of doing my application.
thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @meAtstac, it's ok. Glad it help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Hello bro this code works for me exactly. what this code you do, it will post the post into your album nor in application album.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    if ( isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["error"]==0 )
    {
        $file='images/'.$_FILES["file"]['name'];
        if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$file))
        {
            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
            $post_data = array(
            'name'=>$_POST['album'],
            'description'=>$_POST['album']
            );
            $data['album'] = $facebook->api("/me/albums", 'post', $post_data); 
            //$file = $file_name;
            $post_data = array(
            "message" => $_POST['message'],
            "source" => '@' . realpath($file)
            );
            $album_id = $data['album']['id'];
            $data['photo'] = $facebook->api("/$album_id/photos", 'post', $post_data);
        }
    }
    /**/

}
```

When you upload any picture from your application, facebook creates an album into your profile named as your application. But this code will post the picture into your album.

```
$_POST['album']
```

is the album name which I enter in a textfield. Then I just post the form and uploads photo. I hope this will help you

Comment: thanks for the assistance. I believe that something is wrong with my settings. Not very sure why mine can't work still. But really thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `getSession()` with `getUser()`
because old PHP versions do not identify the `getSession()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
use getUser();
```

Comment: Please add some details to make your answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code and It Will Work Fine For You as Facebook Documentation Here [How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user’s profile](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) Says

```
<?php

       $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
       $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
       $post_login_url = "YOUR_POST-LOGIN_URL";
       $album_name = 'YOUR_ALBUM_NAME';
       $album_description = 'YOUR_ALBUM_DESCRIPTION';

       $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

       //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
       if(empty($code))
         {
           $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
           . "client_id=" . $app_id 
           . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
           . "&scope=publish_stream";
           echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
           "'</script>");
       } 
       else {
         $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
         . "access_token?"
         . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
         . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
         . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
         . "&code=" . $code;
         $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
         $params = null;
         parse_str($response, $params);
         $access_token = $params['access_token'];

         // Create a new album
         $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
         . "access_token=". $access_token;

         $postdata = http_build_query(
         array(
          'name' => $album_name,
          'message' => $album_description
            )
          );
         $opts = array('http' =>
         array(
          'method'=> 'POST',
          'header'=>
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => $postdata
          )
         );
         $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
         $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
           $context));

         // Get the new album ID
         $album_id = $result->id;

         //Show photo upload form and post to the Graph URL
         $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id
           . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
         echo '<html><body>';
         echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
         .$graph_url. ' "method="POST">';
         echo 'Adding photo to album: ' . $album_name .'<br/><br/>';
         echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
         echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
         echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
         echo '<input name="message" type="text"
            value=""><br/><br/>';
         echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>';
         echo '</form>';
         echo '</body></html>';
      }
 ?>
```

Example Response

```
{
   "id": "1001207389476"
}
```